# Agora cloud recording not starting

Tags: rest, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am following [Agora Cloud Recording RESTful apis](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=All%20Platforms)

The problem is

1. Acquire api working fine
2. Start api working fine

Now query api is returning me

```
{
    "resourceId": "rid",
    "sid": "sid",
    "serverResponse": {
        "status": 4,
        "fileList": "",
        "fileListMode": "string",
        "sliceStartTime": 0
    }
}
```

and stop api giving me

```
{
    "resourceId": "rid",
   "sid": "sid",
    "code": 435
}
```

which means no one is present in channel.
But 2 users are there in my ongoing channel

My start request was

```
{
    "cname":"80f350442cb2a26ccacb5cfb058c6e82", 
    "uid":"936239554",       // userid who i want to record...is this correct????
    "clientRequest":{
         "token": "temp_token_generated_from_agora_console",
          "recordingConfig":{
            "channelType":0,
            "streamTypes":2,
            "audioProfile":1,
            "videoStreamType":0,
            "maxIdleTime":120,
            "transcodingConfig":{
                "width":360,
                "height":640,
                "fps":30,
                "bitrate":600,
                "maxResolutionUid":"1",
                "mixedVideoLayout":1
                }
            },
            "subscribeVideoUids": ["936239554"],    // is this correct?? 
            "subscribeAudioUids": ["936239554"],    //is this correct??
        "storageConfig":{
            "vendor":1,
            "region":14,
            "bucket":"my_bucket_name",
            "accessKey":"xxxx",
            "secretKey":"xxxx"
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I am facing the exact same problem, did you found a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

When using Agora's Cloud Recording service, the Recorder instance needs to have its own unique ID that it uses to join the channel and record the other users that are defined in the `"subscribeVideoUids":` portion of the request.

In the code snippet below first UID is meant to be unique for the Recorder to use to join the channel.This is not meant to be the UID for the user you wish to record.

```
 "cname":"80f350442cb2a26ccacb5cfb058c6e82", "uid":"936239554", // userid who i want to record...is this correct????
```

if the user's UID is , `"936239554"` then the recorder should have a different/unique value even just adding an integer to the end `"9362395541"` is enough.

Im the `"subscribeVideoUids"` and `"subscribeAudioUids"` you'll want to include all the UID's of the users in the channel that you want to record. So if there are two users in the channel, include each UID as an element of the Array.

```
"subscribeVideoUids": ["936239554"],"subscribeAudioUids": ["936239554"],
```

Comment: Can you please share some other solution, it is not working, and on another note why we need to append any integer in subscribe video ids? and what if I want to record all users in the channel?

Comment: To record all users, don’t declare the "subscribeVideoUids" and "subscribeAudioUids" keys and the cloud recording will record all users in the channel.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer, I have written you an email in previous days (I found your answers on Agora at medium) and I have attached all my configurations and response. Can you please check there, it would be a great help for me.

Comment: I am on holiday this week, so I have not been checking my email regularly. I will take a look and I can help you troubleshoot via email.

Comment: Hello @Hermes I am facing the same issue can you please help us